# Global Keyboard Hook Spy?

Tags: c++, keyboard

I'm writing up a quick tool in C# thats meant to sort of be a virtual keyboard. At the moment I am using [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx). I want to know if keyloggers would capture the keys so I found [this code](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip69.htm) but i don't have mfc installed so i cant compile nor run it

How might i key if SendKeys is being logged by keyloggers or how do I get the code (snippet below) running in a single exe to test my code with?

```
#include <Windows.h>

static UINT uMsg = 0;
static HWND hWndMain = 0; 
static HHOOK hKeyHook = NULL ; 
#pragma data_seg()

HINSTANCE hInstance = 0; 
HOOKPROC lpfnHookProc = 0; 

LRESULT __stdcall KeyboardFunc (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   BOOL bPassToChain;
   char szDebug [100];

   // Check for exception cases...
   if (nCode < 0)
      return (CallNextHookEx (hKeyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));
   if (nCode == HC_NOREMOVE)
      return (CallNextHookEx (hKeyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));

   switch (wParam)
   {
      case VK_F2:
           wsprintf (szDebug, "F2 key message, lparam = 0x%X\n", lParam);
           OutputDebugString (szDebug);

           // only send on keydown, not keyup (autorepeat)
           if (HIWORD (lParam) & 0xC000)
           {
              OutputDebugString ("F2 Keyup\n");
           }
           else
           {
              wsprintf (szDebug, "Sending F2 keydown message %d to hwnd 0x%X\n",
                        uMsg, hWndMain);
              OutputDebugString (szDebug);
              PostMessage (hWndMain, uMsg, 0, 0);
           }
           bPassToChain = FALSE;
           break;

      default :
           bPassToChain = TRUE ;
           break ;
   }

   if (bPassToChain)
      return (CallNextHookEx (hKeyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));
   else
      return TRUE ; // We have processed this key
} 

BOOL __stdcall InstallExampleKeyboardHook (HWND hWnd, UINT uMyMsg) 
{
   hWndMain = hWnd ; 
   uMsg     = uMyMsg;
   lpfnHookProc = (HOOKPROC) KeyboardFunc ; 
   hKeyHook = SetWindowsHookEx (WH_KEYBOARD, lpfnHookProc, hInstance, NULL);

   if (hKeyHook) 
      return TRUE ; 
   else 
      return FALSE ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing about MFC.  Straight native c++ code.  If you have Visual Studio, you should be able to make a quick console c++ app, copy and paste that code in, and compile and test.  If not, go and get the free but big Windows SDK.  Less friendly then VS, but there's a compiler, so should get you in the right direction.

Low level hooks are not quite debugger friendly, so you might need to trace or log out some helpful statements.

Edited: to get the module handle, you will need something like this:

```
HookModule = LoadLibrary(ModulePath);

HookProc HookFunction = GetProcAddress(HookModule, "GetMessageCallBack");

GetMessageHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_GETMESSAGE, HookFunction, HookModule, 0);
```

Comment: I know this is straight C++ so thats why i copy/pasted it out. But i dont get any msg events :/

Comment: Well I remember writing a LL keyboard hook application using SetWindowsHookEx  and it was perfectly debugger friendly. Just run in under VS debugger and put a breakpoint in KeyboardFunc - it works no problem.

Comment: @acidzombie24, you need a WinMain with message loop because otherwise your program will exit immediaelly after you start it.

Comment: @aleguna: I get 0 and GetlastError gives me --> ERROR_HOOK_NEEDS_HMOD

    1428 (0x594)

    Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle.

Comment: @acidzombie24, well then give a module handle.. `GetModuleHandle (NULL)`. Also use `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` not `WH_KEYBOARD`, because the latter will only work in dll

Comment: @aleguna: I got it working! Thanks. It definatelly needed _LL, idk what that sample was doing cause removing low level causes this not to work at all. Also It appears SendKeys doesnt get logged by the LL hook =). If you make an answer with GetModuleHandle  and _LL (your last comment essentially) i'll accept it

Comment: Please see my additional info on getting the module handle, which is your hook DLL.